# bootstrap dropdowns navbar cant open

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm creating navbar with bootstrap v5. and I'm copying the code from bootstrap website. and I created JavaScript code too but it's not working.
my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>rest api</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  font-family: 'SF Pro Text', 'SF Pro Icons', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica',
    'Arial', sans-serif;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
        </div>
      </nav>
<script>
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if(parent.hasClass('open')) { 
    parent.removeClass('open'); 
  } else {
     parent.addClass('open');
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the bootstrap.js. Also, you are listening for click on the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your CDN that you used is incorrect with the new version of the bootstarp.
the following code is working fine :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>rest api</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<style>
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  font-family: 'SF Pro Text', 'SF Pro Icons', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica',
    'Arial', sans-serif;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
        </div>
      </nav>
<script>
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if(parent.hasClass('open')) { 
    parent.removeClass('open'); 
  } else {
     parent.addClass('open');
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```